# Is it possible to save line item properties in a session?

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, liquid

so I have this website where the user can customize the colors of the different parts of a uniform. So what I currently achieve was using Line Item Property (LIP) to get those selected colors so when the customer checks out and pay, all the values will be passed to the user's email and to the site admin's product dashboard.

Now my question is, is it possible to save each of those LIP values to a session? I am planning to have a Save Design button just in case the user wants to save it first then check out later. When the user clicks on the button, he will have to input his email address so that a link will be sent to his email -- format could be something like: [shopname.com/customizer?designID=8174201a2r](http://shopname.com/customizer?designID=8174201a2r) When he clicks that link, all the colors he previously selected should load. Is that possible with Shopify? If yes, how, so I can do a further research and study on it.

Hope I can receive an advice from the experts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that is absolutely possible setting cookies via Javascript when user fill LIP then getting stored values in cookies to prefill form.